# function inside directive does not show data on client

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I have a directive with inline editing which works perfect, as demonstrated here: [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/A4v3RLBq5WZozMFpsQic?p=preview)

I have another directive that parses a name from 1 input to json data, which also works ok: [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NqQ5m0yJD4LxXTnBAsoE?p=preview)

when I combine the 2 directives, I can get the parsed name json to print in the console but not on the client

see this plunker:  [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/b4F5SADAC2uYbV06tEZH?p=preview)

```
 // this is the save function in the directive 
  scope.save = function() {
    scope.editMode = false;
    parsedName = NameParse.parse(scope.model);
    console.log('Prefix: ' + parsedName.salutation);
    console.log('First Name: ' + parsedName.firstName);
    console.log('Last Name: ' + parsedName.lastName);
    scope.handleSave({value: scope.model});
  };
```

Click the "pencil" icon to edit, then the save button and check the console.  The data is there.  Nothing on the client though.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your directive is using an **isolate scope**. Properties etc. exposed on this scope will not be available to the outer scope by default.

Simplified example of your rendered HTML:

```
<body>

  <span class="editableContainer ng-isolate-scope">
    ...
    Directive's scope available here
    ...
  </span>

  Directive's scope not available here

</body>
```

If you want the outer scope to have access to something exposed on the isolate scope you need to explicitly add it to the scope object hash.

### Solution 1 - Add `parsedName` to the scope object hash:

```
scope: {
  model: '=model',
  parsedName: '=',
  handleSave: '&onSave',
  handleCancel: '&onCancel'
}
```

And:

```
scope.save = function() {
  scope.editMode = false;
  scope.parsedName = NameParse.parse(scope.model);
  scope.handleSave({
    value: scope.model
  });
};
```

HTML:

```
<form-input model="name" parsed-name="parsedName"  ...
```

Controller:

```
// Actually not needed, but usually good for clarity.
$scope.parsedName = {};
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/YCoUiA3KpAouCCd5KQLP?p=preview

---

### Solution 2 - Use the `handleSave` function:

```
// Leave unchanged
scope: {
  model: '=model',
  handleSave: '&onSave',
  handleCancel: '&onCancel'
}
```

And:

```
scope.save = function() {
  scope.editMode = false;
  var parsedName = NameParse.parse(scope.model);
  scope.handleSave({
    name: scope.model,
    parsedName: parsedName
  });
};
```

HTML:

```
<form-input model="name" on-save="saveEditable(name, parsedName)" ...
```

Controller:

```
$scope.saveEditable = function(name, parsedName) {

  $scope.name = name;
  $scope.parsedName = parsedName;
};
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/OZ57jRtuzgn5CZSA5t90?p=preview

Comment: Thank you.  both solutions work.  I like the second one better because I can "disable" the parseName just by taking it out of the on-save parameter.  Thank you again